# r code for topic modelling in latent semantic analysis and PLSA

Tags: r, text, data-mining, text-analytics-api

Can someone please help me with the R code to perform Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis (PLSA) and LSA for topic modelling. I successfully executed the LDA method.

Comment: Please publish, what you try to do to this time (you code)

Answer (score 0):

you can use SVS package in [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svs/svs.pdf)

it has a function called "fast_psa" for probabilistic latent semantic analysis. Here is the example from the documentation, hope it helps:

```
install.packages("svs")
library(svs)
SndT_Fra <- read.table(system.file("extdata", "SndT_Fra.txt", package = "svs"),
                   header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", encoding = "UTF-8")
psa.SndT_Fra <- fast_psa(SndT_Fra, k = 7)
psa.SndT_Fra
```